# Replace character X with character Y in a string with bash

Tags: bash, text-processing, scripting

I am making **bash** script and I want to replace one character with another character in my string variable.

Example:

```
#!/bin/sh

string="a,b,c,d,e"
```

And I want to replace `,` with `\n`.

output:

```
string="a\nb\nc\nd\ne\n"
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You want to replace `,` with literal `\n` or newline?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

So many ways, here are a few:

```
$ string="a,b,c,d,e"

$ echo "${string//,/$'\n'}"  ## Shell parameter expansion
a
b
c
d
e

$ tr ',' '\n' <<<"$string"  ## With "tr"
a
b
c
d
e

$ sed 's/,/\n/g' <<<"$string"  ## With "sed"
a
b
c
d
e

$ xargs -d, -n1 <<<"$string"  ## With "xargs"
a
b
c
d
e
```