# Replacing trailing text POSIX-ly

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, posix

As I did not find a direct way to supply the file name to the `pv` ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv)), (*except for a strange `-N` switch, which acts as a prefix, rather than the file name itself*), I would need to manually edit the end of text which `sha512sum` or any other shaXsum for that matter outputs over pipe like:

```sh
pv -W "$file" | sha512sum -b
```

I store it in a variable `sha_output`, but I wanted to give you *purer* example, the raw code is:

```sh
sha_output=$( pv -W "$file" | sha512sum -b )
```

---

Example hash sum text output:

```
2a19f5852ba8f76bd5a67db18539d609baaf3888b27a57181564db01ef6c16812c60e306973edc059221f61bf2ad9f4b4ef5ff09bbcef98e74a27971c67bdc18 *-
```

Desired output:

```
2a19f5852ba8f76bd5a67db18539d609baaf3888b27a57181564db01ef6c16812c60e306973edc059221f61bf2ad9f4b4ef5ff09bbcef98e74a27971c67bdc18  linuxmint-19.2-cinnamon-64bit.iso
```

(Yes, 2 spaces in between the hash and the file name).

Finally, let us suppose the file name is stored in a variable called `file_name`.

---

Solutions must not include any [Bashisms](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism), only portable ([POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)) solutions, please.

With the help of this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/272597/126755), I put together the following:

```sh
printf '%s\n' "${sha_output//\*-/$file_name}"
```

which surprisingly works (somewhat) under Bash, but Dash errors out with message:

> ```
> bad substitution
> ```

Since brace expansion is not defined by POSIX, as per comment, it is by no surprise then.

Comment: `dash` wouldn't grok the `${variable//pattern/word}` substitution as it's not POSIX. Also, brace expansion is not POSIX either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `$file` is the name or pathname of the single file that you'd like to substitute into the checksum output.

```
pv "$file" | sha256sum | { IFS=' ' read sum junk && printf '%s  %s\n' "$sum" "$file"; }
```

The last part of the pipeline reads the checksum and whatever else `sha256sum` output on its first line, and then prints the checksum out followed by the original filename.

Note that using `sha256sum -b` isn't really needed as these tools make no difference between binary and text files on Unix.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are capturing the command output already in a variable, you could "Capture and Correct" the var (POSIXly, yes runs in dash):

```
sha_output=$( pv -W "$file" | sha512sum -b)
sha_output="${sha_output%\*-} $file"
```

The `${...%\*-}` will remove the trailing `*-` and then an space and the file name are appended. Actually, the `-b` mode is only useful in OS that diferentiate binary mode from text mode when accesing a file (namely only MS-DOS). So, no `-b` option is needed for `shaXsum`, and the asterisk (`*`) (signaling binary mode) will become an space (signaling text mode).

If you are not capturing but want the output printed, you can use:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$(pv "$file" | sha256sum | sed 's/-$//')$file"
2a19f5852 ... a27971c67bdc18  linuxmint-19.2-cinnamon-64bit.iso
```

Or [@Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/555029/265604) answer.

All answers are equally valid, POSIX compatible and useful.

---

Note that all the above doesn't mimic the exact behaviour of `shaXsum` in that some file names (with newline or slash) will make the hash line start with a backslash.

If `file='wo\\rds'` (contains a backslash) the output is:

```
$ sha256sum "$file"
\f6c94d35691b9c356f7e5072f94d23f127b168cf9b04f0f5b26e0cb1f6ef4414  wo\\rds
```

Note that the line start with a backslash and that problematic characters in the file name are escaped with a backslash.

Your command doesn't mimic that:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$(pv "$file" | sha256sum | sed 's/-$//')$file"
f6c94d35691b9c356f7e5072f94d23f127b168cf9b04f0f5b26e0cb1f6ef4414  wo\rds
```

Comment: At this moment I find your solution more elegant, but which one to actually use? Well, I upvoted. Waiting for you maybe to append additional information which would help me decide. Thanks.

Comment: All answers are equally valid, POSIX compatible and useful. It is perfectly fine your present selection if that helped you, we are not competing but cooperating to help questioners. @LinuxSecurityFreak

Comment: Good morning! I see you've updated your answer. I've read it and I am proud to be a member here. Cheers and thanks again!