# how to replace spaces in a string with '\ ' in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, text-formatting

I'm writing a bash script that prints the contents of a file called `website` (using `cat`) that is inside a folder with a space in it's name, for example `folder 1`. but I can't make bash get the path correct, it always uses only the first word in the folder name, so `cat folder/website` instead of `cat folder 1/website`. so I want to replace the space with `\` .
I tried using `sed` and `tr`, but they didn't work.

here is my code:

```bsh
function get-website() {
    DIR="$1"
    website="$(cat "main/apps/$DIR/website")"
}
```

most of what I tried is here: [Replace character X with character Y in a string with bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272596/replace-character-x-with-character-y-in-a-string-with-bash)

thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you call your function in your code?  Also, if you just want to print the contents of the file, why are you storing it in a variable?

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm storing it in a vaiable because I also need it later.

Comment: So, how are you calling your function?

Comment: @Kusalananda that was the problem, how I was calling it: `get-website $2` instead of `get-website "$2"`.
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the function directory name quoted.

```
$ type foo
foo is a function
foo () 
{ 
    dir="${1}";
    cat "${dir}/test"
}
$ foo "folder 1"
foobar
$ foo folder 1
cat: folder/test: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Not sure why you've got `type foo`...?

Comment: `type foo` shows content of `foo` function which mimics yours `get-website`.

Comment: I know what it does. I just don't see the relevance of it in your question. Just start with the third line, `foo()`

Comment: the problem was how I was calling the function (as @Kusalananda asked) as well as how the code itself inside the function was. thanks a lot everyone.